# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 \pi y}$ $\leq $ $2e^{-\pi y}$ When $y \geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

How can I show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 \pi y}$ $\leq $ $2e^{-\pi y}$ When $y \geq 1$. On using the inequality with the integral I get: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 \pi y} \leq \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\pi y t}dt = \frac{e^{-\pi y}}{\pi y}$.  From here I can conclude that the summation have the desired upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach. For reasons of personal preference I shall replace the $y$ in your notation with $\alpha \geqslant 1$ and introduce $a \colon=\mathrm{e}^{-\pi \alpha}$. It is clear that $0<a \leqslant \mathrm{e}^{-\pi}<\mathrm{e}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}<\frac{1}{2}$.

We can produce the following estimate:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n^2}=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}}a^{n^2}=\sum_{m \in \left(\mathbb{N}^{\times}\right)^{\underline{2}}}a^m \leqslant \sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}}a^m=\frac{a}{1-a},$$
which relies on the fact that for a sequence of positive reals, the sum of the associated series coincides with the sum of the sequence understood in the general sense of *summation of arbitrary families in topological groups*. The notation $\left(\mathbb{N}^{\times}\right)^{\underline{2}}=\left\{m^2\right\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}}$ expresses the set of all nonzero square natural numbers and in order to obtain the sum of the right-most (geometric) series we relied on the condition that $a<1$.

This upper bound can be used to reach the desired conclusion as long as we manage to establish that in the given situation $\frac{a}{1-a} \leqslant 2a$, which amounts to claiming that $a \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ and is indeed a condition we have already ascertained $a$ to satisfy.

This concludes the solution.

**P.S.** An equally valid manner of justifying the inequality $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n^2} \leqslant \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n$ is to simply the remark the term-wise comparison $a^{n^2} \leqslant a^n$ occurring between the two series in question, as $n^2 \geqslant n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a<1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n$ holds simply because $(n^2)$ is a subsequence of $(n)$ and all terms are non-negative.

Comment: @MartinR That is of course another way of looking at it, which is in spirit quite close to the argument I gave in the second paragraph.